# Powershell validate input

Tags: validation, powershell, match, limit

I'm trying to validate some input in powershell.
The user should enter a username for a new AD user. This username should be validated for any invalid characters (e.g !, $, ;, etc). 
Valid characters are a-z (upper and lower), 0-9, _, - and ,

Thanks for any help.

At the moment my code looks like this:

```
do{

    $input="notok"
    # Eingabe es Usernamen
    Write-Host "Bite den Usernamen eingeben"
    $Username = Read-Host


    if ($Username -notmatch "[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]") {
        Write-Host ""
        Write-Host "ACHTUNG: Benutzer $Username enthaelt ungueltige Zeichen (nur a-z, A-Z, 0-9, ., - und _ erlaubt), bitte die Eingabe wiederholen" -ForegroundColor Red
        Write-Host ""
        $input="notok"

    }else{

        $input="ok"

    }

}while($input -ne "ok")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
do{

    $input="notok"
    # Eingabe es Usernamen
    Write-Host "Bite den Usernamen eingeben"
    $Username = Read-Host


    if ($Username -notmatch "^[a-z0-9_.-]*$") {
        Write-Host ""
        Write-Host "ACHTUNG: Benutzer $Username enthaelt ungueltige Zeichen (nur a-z, A-Z, 0-9, ., - und _ erlaubt), bitte die Eingabe wiederholen" -ForegroundColor Red
        Write-Host ""
        $input="notok"

    }else{

        $input="ok"

    }

}while($input -ne "ok")
```

Comment: No prob =) Though you should check out Campbell's answer if you are using a function, it's a much neater way of doing it. Of course if it's halfway through the script you'll have to stick with this.

Comment: Nice, but please add an explanation (the one you've already given in a comment on @campbell.rw's answer).

Comment: Regex isn't really my thing but what you had was just asking if any of those characters was in $Username. Using `"^[a-z0-9_.-]*$"` instead (most notably the ^ before and *$ after) is saying ALL characters must match.

Comment: Indeed, that's the correct explanation, which I was hoping you'd _add to your answer_, because not many people pay attention to _comments_. As it stands, the only difference between your code and the OP's is the addition of `^` and `$`, which - while crucial - is currently not obvious.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a parameter, and use the built in parameter validation:

```
Param(
  [Parameter(Mandatory=$false,ValueFromPipeline=$true)] 
  [ValidateScript({$_-match "^[a-zA-Z0-9_\-,]+$"})] 
  [String]
  $Username
)
```

Comment: This is assuming that he is using a function which I agree with but your regex is only checking that any of those characters are contained, not that ALL characters match the expression. You need the one I posted.

Comment: `[ValidateScript({$_-match "^[a-z0-9_.-]*$"})]`

Comment: @Deadly-Bagel - it doesn't need to be a function, you can also use the parameter is it's just a straight-up .ps1 script

Comment: Huh, learn something new every day. You need the Mandatory parameter for it to prompt you halfway through the script though.

Comment: Using parameter validation is an elegant solution; the caveat is that, unfortunately, you do not get to control the error message that is output (from what I can tell), and that message is likely *too technical* for end users, because the raw script block is printed.
Aside from that: in the case at hand, the simpler `ValidatePattern` attribute would suffice: `[ValidatePattern('^[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]$')]`.